# Synchronizing LDAP groups with Wiki

Tags: ldap, wiki, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

How synchronizing LDAP groups with Wiki groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Extension:LDAP Authentication](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLDAP_Authentication). Features: Synchronization of LDAP groups to MediaWiki security groups (LDAP->MediaWiki only)